# How to produce a character like  (the nonexisting \mathbb{k})?

Tags: unicode-math

How to produce a character like  (the nonexisting `\mathbb{k}`) in a TeX file?

Comment: You have tagged the question unicode-math if you are using that package it should work as unicode math fonts have lower case double struck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tagged this `unicode-math`, it should just work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

$$ (the nonexisting $\mathbb{k}$)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that \Bbbk with `amssymb` package can also do it.